# Remote host closed connection during handshake - Help a noob

Tags: java, ssl, keytool, handshake

Anybody how can help telling what could be causing this:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/openhab $ sudo ./start.sh
Launching the openHAB runtime...
osgi> 00:09:50.841 INFO  o.o.c.internal.CoreActivator[:92] - openHAB runtime has been started (v1.3.1).
00:10:26.588 INFO  o.o.m.c.i.ModelRepositoryImpl[:99] - Loading model 'test.items'
00:10:35.225 INFO  o.o.i.s.i.DiscoveryServiceImpl[:92] - mDNS service has been started
00:10:42.865 INFO  o.o.m.c.i.ModelRepositoryImpl[:99] - Loading model 'test.sitemap'
00:10:57.579 INFO  o.o.i.r.i.RESTApplication[:158] - Started REST API at /rest
00:11:03.592 INFO  o.o.u.w.i.s.WebAppServlet[:99] - Started Classic UI at /openhab.app
00:11:18.138 INFO  o.o.b.i.internal.IhcConnection[:139] - Connecting to IHC / ELKO LS controller [IP='192.168.1.20:443' Username='admin' Password='pass'].
00:11:23.928 ERROR o.o.b.i.internal.IhcConnection[:188] - Connection to IHC / ELKO LS controller failed.
**javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)**
00:11:24.032 INFO  o.o.c.s.AbstractActiveService[:189] - IHC / ELKO LS refresh and notification listener service has been started
00:12:02.482 INFO  o.o.i.r.i.RESTApplication[:174] - Stopped REST API
00:12:06.826 INFO  o.o.u.w.i.s.WebAppServlet[:110] - Stopped Classic UI
```

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace. Edit it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

I feel it is caused by certificate validation problem.  Are using CA signed or self signed certificate? If you dont have any certificate use java keytool to generate your own certificates.

some more details on this will be helpful.